# Downloading SharePoint online list items' attachments locally will not allow me to open those files (seems the file are corrupted)

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online, filestream

I have a SharePoint online list , and this list contain items with attachments. so i want to download all the list item attachems. so i wrote this PnP Power Shell sript:-

```
  $ApprovalListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List "tickets" -PageSize 1000 -ScriptBlock { Param($items) $items.Context.ExecuteQuery()} | ForEach-Object {
     
  $ctx = Get-PnPContext
  $spSourceWeb= Get-PnPWeb
    
  $ItemAttachmentURLPrefix = 'https://****.sharepoint.com/Lists/tickets/Attachments/'+$_['ID']+'/'
  $attachmentCollection = ForEach-Object{Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $_ -Property "AttachmentFiles"}
    
  $AttachmentSeq = 0
  ForEach($Attachment in $attachmentCollection)
            {
            Write-Host "`tDownloading Attachement: " $attachment $ItemAttachmentURLPrefix
            
            $AttachmentSeq++
    
            $AttachmentDataObj = "" | Select "Attachment Seq", "JDE Company", "Vendor Number", "Vendor Invoice Number", "Attachment Name", "Attachment System Name", "Job-run Date/Time Stamp"
    Write-Host $Attachment.FileName
            $file = Get-PnPFile -Url ($ItemAttachmentURLPrefix + $Attachment.FileName)
            $bytes = (Get-PnPFile -Url ($ItemAttachmentURLPrefix + $Attachment.FileName)).OpenBinaryStream()
            $name = "C:\Attachments\"+$Attachment.FileName
             $fs = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($name, "OpenOrCreate") 
            $fs.Write($bytes, 0 , $bytes.Length)    
            $fs.Close() 
            $stream = $streamResult.Value
            Write-Host $file.Name
            Write-Host $stream.Name
            }
   }
```

but the files that will get saved can not be opened, for example this excel sheet will raise this error:-

[image]

while a pdf will raise this error:-

[image]

any advice what is wrong with my script?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use PnP PowerShell code in below format to download list item attachments to local folder:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/dev -Interactive

$listitem = Get-PnPListItem -List Employee -Id 2  
$attachments = ForEach-Object {Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $listitem -Property "AttachmentFiles"}  

$attachments | ForEach-Object { Get-PnPFile -Url $_.ServerRelativeUrl -FileName $_.FileName -Path "E:\SharePoint\Documents" -AsFile }
```

**Source**: [Read items attachments and write them to local folder](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/305249/read-items-attachments-and-write-them-to-local-folder)